# Get a set of coordinates between two points?

Tags: java

What I have so far is:

```
public static List<String> getIds(int x, int y, int range) {

    int ax = x+range;
    int ay = y+range;

    int bx = x-range;
    int by = y-range;

    System.out.println(Point2D.distance(ax, ay, bx, by));

    // get all coordinates between those two points above.
    // and add them to the string array like "x,y";

    return null;
}
```

I used the Point2D.distance to make sure the range was right, but for this method I need to get all the coordinates (integers not doubles) between `[ax,ay]` and `[bx,by]` yet I cannot find any utility methods within Point2D which does this.

Comment: Do you want all the coordinates within the bounds of all along a straight line of?  And at what level granularity?

Comment: Imagine those two coordinates as being two corners of a cuboid (top right and bottom left). I would like to get all the coordinates within that cuboid.

Comment: is it correct that 'by' is the same value as 'ay'?

Comment: Can you give an example of input, with expected output.  And can we consider it a cuboid, which would be three dimensional, or to be all of the points inside of a rectangle with the line connecting these two points being the diagonal?

Comment: Great :)  Also, (ax,ay) (bx,by) is simply a square with sides length 2*range - and you just want the points on the diagonal - so (bx, by) , (bx+1, by+1), (bx+2, by+2) ,....... yes?

Comment: for getting the points, it only needs to be considered a 2D Square (not a 3d cuboid sorry). the game has 3 dimensions, but for this method i only need a top-view. mixing up my shapes today..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the points, you'd need nested loops like :

```
for (int i = -range; i <= range; i++) {
    for (int j = -range; j <= range; j++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("(%d,%d)", x+i, y+j));
    }
}
```